# Arduino LED matrix and 2D array, data seems to be corrupting

Tags: arduino, led-matrix

I'm trying to drive an 8x8 LED matrix with an arduino nano, but I can't get the LEDs to display what I tell it to.

I'm using [this](http://www.aliexpress.com/store/product/Free-shipping-10-pcs-8-8-3-75MM-Red-16P-dot-matrix-module-Dimensions-38-38/605870_879542981.html) LED Matrix

Here's my code:

```cpp
int row1 = 2;
int row2 = 3;
int row3 = 4;
int row4 = 5;
int row5 = 6;
int row6 = 7;
int row7 = 8;
int row8 = 9;

int col1 = 10;
int col2 = 11;
int col3 = 12;
int col4 = 18;
int col5 = 14;
int col6 = 15;
int col7 = 16;
int col8 = 17;

void setup() {
  int i;
  for(i = 2; i <= 18; i++) {
    pinMode(i,OUTPUT);
  }
  for(i = 2; i <= 9; i++) {
    digitalWrite(i, HIGH);
  }
}

void loop() {

  int display [8][8] = {
  {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
  {0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0},
  {0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0},
  {0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0},
  {0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0},
  {0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0},
  {0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0},
  {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1}
  };

  updateScreen(display);
}

void updateScreen(int screen[8][8]) {

  Serial.begin(9600);
  int i;
  for (i = row1; i <= row8; i++) {
    Serial.println(i-1); 
    digitalWrite(i, LOW);
      digitalWrite(col8, screen[i-2][0]);
      Serial.print(screen[i-2][0]); Serial.print("|"); 
      digitalWrite(col7, screen[i-2][1]);
      Serial.print(screen[i-2][1]); Serial.print("|"); 
      digitalWrite(col6, screen[i-2][2]);
      Serial.print(screen[i-2][2]); Serial.print("|"); 
      digitalWrite(col5, screen[i-2][3]);
      Serial.print(screen[i-2][3]); Serial.print("|"); 
      digitalWrite(col4, screen[i-2][4]);
      Serial.print(screen[i-2][4]); Serial.print("|"); 
      digitalWrite(col3, screen[i-2][5]);
      Serial.print(screen[i-2][5]); Serial.print("|"); 
      digitalWrite(col2, screen[i-2][6]);
      Serial.print(screen[i-2][6]); Serial.print("|"); 
      digitalWrite(col1, screen[i-2][7]);
      Serial.println(screen[i-2][7]);
      delay(1);
      blank();
    digitalWrite(i, HIGH);
  }

}

void blank() {
  digitalWrite(col1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(col2, LOW);
  digitalWrite(col3, LOW);
  digitalWrite(col4, LOW);
  digitalWrite(col5, LOW);
  digitalWrite(col6, LOW);
  digitalWrite(col7, LOW);
  digitalWrite(col8, LOW);
}
```

And here is the output:

```cpp
1 
1|0|0|0|0|0|0|0 
2 
0|1|0|0|0|0|0|0 
3 
0|0|1|0|0|0|0|0 
4 
0|0|0|1|0|0|0|0 
5 
0|0|0|0|1|0|0¾j 
6 
0|0|0|0|0|1|0|0 
7 
0|0|0|0|0|0|1|0 
8 
0|0|0|0|0|0|0|1
```

So I can tell that the error (probably) isn't my wiring, because those array values are clearly wrong, I have no idea where the `¾j` is coming from.

Comment: All your array indexing looks wrong, the array `display` will have indexes going from 0-7 and for example you have `row8` declared as 9.

Comment: That should be fine, as the program doesn't use the index to get the position.

Comment: There was a bug with the indexing, the `[i-1]`s should have been `[i-2]`s. that has eliminated the last line. Here's the new output:

`1
1|0|0|0|0|0|0|0
2
0|1|0|0|0|0|0|0
3
0|0|1|0|0|0|0|0
4
0|0|0|1|0|0|0|0
5
0|0|0|0|1|0|0¾j
6
0|0|0|0|0|1|0|0
7
0|0|0|0|0|0|1|0
8
0|0|0|0|0|0|0|1`

Comment: There was also a wiring mistake, which is fixed now. However now I can get some patterns to display fine, but others wont. If I use the array full of 1's, I get the whole matrix lit up, but if I use the one that alternates 1's and 0's columns 1 and 7 wont light.

EDIT: And row 8 is showing 7's data, but they aren't switched when using other paterns

Comment: One thing that might be worth a try is a small delay after `digitalWrite(i, LOW)` - I assume that's a clock or latch of some sort. But it's probably worth editing the question to include some info on the LCD you're using and the type of Arduino, how it's connected etc.

Comment: Oh its just a basic LED matrix, no clocks or anything fancy. I think its [this](http://www.aliexpress.com/store/product/Free-shipping-10-pcs-8-8-3-75MM-Red-16P-dot-matrix-module-Dimensions-38-38/605870_879542981.html)

Comment: @user168057  Just FYI. There is now a stack dedicated to Arduino http://arduino.stackexchange.com

Comment: I'd probably be a good idea to try using `uint8_t` instead of `int` for your variables, if you can be certain they'll all be less then `255`. 8-bit variables are both faster, and will take up half the ram. It's *possible* you're corrupting the stack by using too much memory.

Comment: I will give that a try EDIT: No luck, same issues

Comment: I've never used an Arduino but looking at the documentation the Nano only has 14 digital pins. It might be worth taking a step back and just trying to turn on each row one by one - I think you must have connections to something that's not really a digital output (that could cause your UART problem too if one is the transmit line).

Comment: Yeah I was going to use a shift register to get the extra digital I/O but the analogue pins are actually just digital pins connected to an ADC, so they can be used as digital pins if needed.

Comment: Nevermind I found the issue, I used a few `.` instead of `,` in the array declaration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you're reading outside the bounds of `screen`. Screen has valid addresses of 0-7, and you're trying to read from `screen[8][n]`.

```
8
887|22021|-15872|-30720|124|2|9|10
```

^ How can you have line "8"? The line number is `Serial.println(i-1);`, and the value is `Serial.print(screen[i-1][0]);`, so the error will be present in the array access as well. To fix it, you just need to change to `screen[i-2]`.

---

Ok, the *other* corruption  (`6` `0|0|0|0|0|0|Á`) issue is because you're heavily oversaturating the serial port. I stuck a 1 second delay in after each loop, and it fixed that issue.

Change:

```
void loop() {

  static int display [8][8] = {
  {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
  {0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0},
  {0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0},
  {0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0},
  {0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0},
  {0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0},
  {0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0},
  {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1}
  };

  updateScreen(display);

  delay(1000);          //  <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
}
```

or

```
void updateScreen(int screen[8][8]) {

  Serial.begin(115200);
  int i;
  <snip>
```

Output:

```
0
1|0|0|0|0|0|0|0
1
0|1|0|0|0|0|0|0
2
0|0|1|0|0|0|0|0
3
0|0|0|1|0|0|0|0
4
0|0|0|0|1|0|0|0
5
0|0|0|0|0|1|0|0
6
0|0|0|0|0|0|1|0
7
0|0|0|0|0|0|0|1
```

I also tried simply increasing the baud-rate (to `115200` baud), and that also fixed the issue without the delay, so either option would work.

Comment: Static was no help unfortunately. I was originally declaring it outside all functions, but the compiler didn't like it for some reason

Comment: @user168057 - I was wrong, hang on, tinkering with stuff now. I just need to remember how array pointers work.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that earlier, `i-1` should have been `i-2`. I mentioned that in the other comment thread, i'll update the post now.

Comment: @user168057 - I tested it with that fix and it works.